# What to do with main(), if main() only starts another thread with timer job?

Tags: java, timer

My main() method has just one line - I start another thread where Quartz library Timer infinitely triggers some 5-minute timer-task (a few times every day). So main method does nothing, timer-task method for 99% of time also does nothing.

But I need to do something, that main() method does not exit, because then Quartz timer thread would also be killed.

What is the best solution?

Besides, I would like to lessen load on cloud server (where it all works) - so making an infinite loop in main is definitely bad idea.

Comment: You could wait for a keypress in your main method, that will block your main thread and let the scheduler have fun until you think the program should terminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just not call `scheduler#shutdown` in your main method. From my understanding the main method won't shut down until that method is called.

```
  import org.quartz.Scheduler;
  import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
  import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
  import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
  import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
  import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;

  public class QuartzTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {
              Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

              scheduler.start();

              scheduler.shutdown();  //take out this line

          } catch (SchedulerException se) {
              se.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

The code above is pulled directly from the [Quartz documentation Quick Start](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start.html) which states:

> Once you obtain a scheduler using
>   StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(), your application will not
>   terminate until you call scheduler.shutdown(), because there will be
>   active threads.

So just remove the shutdown method.

If you really need an alternative you can start your scheduler and then sleep your main thread "forever". There isn't a much of a load so your server should be fine, but it does waste resources to just sleep an entire thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throw Exception {
   //code here to start your tasks
   while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
   }
}
```